# Situación con Adaptive Server Enterprise al crear una proxy table

Tags: base-de-datos, wsdl, sap, sybase, xml-rpc

Tengo este wsdl en wsdl (RPC/encoded):

```
    <wsdl:definitions xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" xmlns:tns="http://xmlns.example.com/16325154873ss59" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" name="Untitled" targetNamespace="http://xmlns.example.com/16325154873ss59">
<wsdl:types/>
<wsdl:service name="WSDL-service4.serviceagent">
<wsdl:port name="Endpoint" binding="tns:EndpointBinding">
<soap:address location="http://rdtambw01:10109/Services/HelloN/Endpoint%20"/>
</wsdl:port>
</wsdl:service>

<wsdl:portType name="PortType">
<wsdl:operation name="Operation">
<wsdl:input message="tns:Message"/>
<wsdl:output message="tns:Message1"/>
</wsdl:operation>
</wsdl:portType>
<wsdl:binding name="EndpointBinding" type="tns:PortType">
<soap:binding style="rpc" transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http"/>
<wsdl:operation name="Operation">
<soap:operation style="rpc" soapAction="/Services/HelloN/OperationName"/>
<wsdl:input>
<soap:body use="encoded" encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" parts="_part1e"/>
</wsdl:input>
<wsdl:output>
<soap:body use="encoded" encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" parts="part1 part2"/>
</wsdl:output>
</wsdl:operation>
</wsdl:binding>
<wsdl:message name="Message">
<wsdl:part name="_part1e" type="xs:string"/>
</wsdl:message>
<wsdl:message name="Message1">
<wsdl:part name="part1" type="xs:string"/>
<wsdl:part name="part2" type="xs:string"/>
</wsdl:message>
</wsdl:definitions>
```

Al ejecutarlo en sybase me regresa el error adjunto:

```
 sp_webservices 'add', 'http://rdtambw01:10109/Process/Procesos/WSDL/Prueba2/WSDL/WSDL-service4.serviceagent?wsdl'
```

[image: Error Sybase]